# React Native changing let value does not get changed in child component as props

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, ecmascript-6, jsx

Hey I got little bit stuck on this problem. Whole problem is that I can't use state inside navigationOptions. So I tried this:

I declare my let `let isFilterVisible: boolean = false;`

There is navigationOptions block where I call function inside onPress event.

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }: NavigationInjectedProps) => ({
    headerRight: (
            <FilterButton onPress={() => {Installations.handleFilterVisibility(isfilterVisibile)}}/>
   ),
});
```

Simple `static` function where I handle value

```
static handleFilterVisibility(filterVisibility: boolean){
    isfilterVisibile = !filterVisibility;
}
```

Then it's passed to child as props

```
<Filter isFilterVisible={isfilterVisibile}/>
```

Everything seems fine but when I try to log props in child component.

`ComponentDidUpdate` even `ComponentWillReceiveProps` does not log anything.

Any ideas where might be mistake?

Comment: Those functions start with a lower-case `c`; is it possible they don't get called in the first place because you have `ComponentDidUpdate`?

Comment: would be better to provide the entire code snippet.

Comment: Yeah, try creating a [mcve] on codesandbox.io.

Comment: @ChrisG just my typo here. It's lower-case in code. And about codesanbox. Gonna try it but my project is really complex gonna be hard to duplicate it to sanbox.

Comment: Don't copy over the entire project. You need to create a minimal example that reproduces the problem. (It's a trick to make people debug their code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally I solved this thanks to navigation `params`, solution:

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }: NavigationInjectedProps) => ({
    headerRight: (
            <FilterButton onPress={() => {
                const {params = {}} = navigation.state;
                params.handleFilterVisibility()
            }}/>
    ),
});

handleFilterVisibility = () => {
    const { isFilterVisible } = this.state;
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    this.setState({isFilterVisible: !isFilterVisible}, () => {
        navigation.setParams({ 
            isFilterVisible
        });
    })
}

componentDidMount() {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    const { isFilterVisible } = this.state;
    navigation.setParams({
        handleFilterVisibility: this.handleFilterVisibility,
        isFilterVisible
    });
}
```